# Xamarin dismiss popup window

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, native

I have an issue , when SavedAyasListView_ItemLongClick event fires, a popupwindow appears with some buttons, and my intention is whenever i click btnDeleteAya button , perform some actions and dismiss the popup.
When the event fires, the popup appears and when i click the btnDeleteAya the action gets performed and the popup disappears, but when i do the same thing again the popup window doesnt get closed.
I want it to get closed each time i click the btnDeleteAya button not by just clicking outside because that part works as expected.
Here's the code:

```
        public string itemclicked;
        PopupWindow mpopup;
        private void SavedAyasListView_ItemLongClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemLongClickEventArgs e)
        {
            View popUpView = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SavedAyasPopupMenu,
            null); // inflating popup layout
            mpopup = new PopupWindow(popUpView, 800, 500); // Creation of popup
            mpopup.SetBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
            mpopup.OutsideTouchable = true;
            mpopup.Focusable = true;
            mpopup.ShowAtLocation(popUpView, GravityFlags.Center, 10, 50);
            itemclicked = savedAyasListView.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position).ToString();

            Button btnDeleteAya = popUpView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnDeleteAya);
            btnDeleteAya.Click += BtnDeleteAya_Click;
            btnDeleteAya.Click += delegate
            {
                mpopup.Dismiss();
            };

            Button fbShareSavedAya = popUpView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.fbShareSavedAya);
            fbShareSavedAya.Click += FbShareSavedAya_Click;

        }
```

Comment: I test your code and it works fine on my side. Every time the Click event fires, the `PopupWindow` appears and when I click the `btnDeleteAya` the action gets performed,

Comment: The action gets performed but the popup window doesnt get closed after the first time :(

Comment: when you click the `btnDeleteAya` button, the popup window doesnt get closed?

Comment: yes only the first time, not after the first time.

Comment: It works fine on my side, could you please share a basic demo that could reproduce this problem?